# Where's the line of demarcation with Server Fault?

Tags: discussion, questions

I have a question about WordPress and LDAP on a Unix platform, is the appropriate place for that Server Fault or here?

Comment: What's the actual Q? We could likely take it here, assuming it's enough about Linux & Unix.

Comment: The general question is in the title. I'm just offering my specific question as an example of something I'm unsure of as a result. I just didn't know where to post it so I did a general meta question.

Comment: Yeah I know, but answering your Q is a bit like asking if a turning test is accurate enough. I need to test it with the actual Q. My $0.02 is if you ask it we can probably answer it. The help is pretty clear (an intentionally vague) on this subject as well 8-) [on-topic](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) vs. [off-topic](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: I'll add this and stop bugging you, on boarder-line questions like this I'll often leave it to the OP to make the call. Caleb had asked his [Q on SF](http://serverfault.com/questions/575836/what-access-rights-could-be-blocking-access-to-a-gitlab-repository) but then posted the URL in our chat to get us to look at it. So you might want to use the same tactic here.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't, exactly. Server Fault is:

> [a site for system and network administrators needing expert answers related to managing computer systems in a professional capacity.](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic)

while we're:

> [for users of Linux, FreeBSD and other Un*x-like operating systems.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

so naturally there's lots of overlap. If it belongs on both you can pick which one you think you'll get a better answer on. In this case, I wouldn't expect WordPress to be particularly sysadmin-oriented, but SF has [quite a few questions about it](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/wordpress), and certainly LDAP is on-topic there. Setting up any app on Unix is likely to be on-topic for us, so your question is probably fine on either site